# VS Code - Python Debugging - Step into internal functions

Tags: python, function, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In VS Code, the step-by-step debugger won't step into internal functions, and instead, after the function is called it immediately assign the return value. how should I change my configuration in `launch.json` for this to happen?

current `launch.json` file:

```
{
    ...,
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I changed `JustMyCode` to `false` and as expected, it steps into some fundamental files I'm neither familiar with nor need.

The question is: What should I do so that my python debugger in VS Code steps into internal functions

For E.g. you have a function to calculate the factorial of the given number `n`.  after selecting `Run and Debug` in VS Code, I press the pause sign on the top so the program does not continue after I give the input to it. after I give the input, the program continues step by step with my clicks only (line by line with each `Step Over` or `F10` button. when the main program reaches where the internal factorial function is called and I press `F10`, the line-by-line execution does not go inside the factorial function. Instead, it assigns the returned value from the factorial function.

```
def factorial(n):
    ans = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        ans*=i
    return ans

x = int(input())
answer = factorial(x)
print(answer)
```

Imagine the first line is `def factorial(n)`. When the program starts, the step over debugging goes like this:

7,8,9

whereas I want it to go like this:

7,8,2,3,4,3,4,...,5,8,9

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear are you saying setting `justMyCode` does get you what you need, but also steps into modules you don't want to step into? There's no easy way to make it more fine-grained. Or are you saying `"justMyCode": false` still doesn't allow you to step into function you want to step into? (and can you provide a concrete example?)

Comment: The second one. the `JustMyCode` still does not do the job.@Grismar

Comment: You should use F11 (Step Into) instead of F10 (Step Over) to, well... step into the code? Your question only mentions F10, have you tried F11?

Comment: @Grismar My god I did not try it!!! thank you very much for answering. It worked. I'm thinking about deleting this question I felt ashamed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation of debug is clearly stated in the [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_debug-actions). "step into" is `F11`.

[image]

- Continue / Pause `F5`
- Step Over `F10`
- Step Into `F11`
- Step Out `Shift+F11`
- Restart `Ctrl+Shift+F5`
- Stop `Shift+F5`